# Change json.dumps behaviour : customize serialization

Tags: python, json, string, serialization

Imagine, I've got a dict `{"a": "hello", "b": b"list"}`

- 'a' is a string
- 'b' is a byte string

I would like to serialize the dict into the "json"(*) string --> '{"a": "hello", "b": list}'

(*) : not really json compliant

For that, i've written that method, it works ....

```py
def stringify(obj):
    def my(obj):
        if isinstance(obj,bytes):
            return "<:<:%s:>:>" % obj.decode()
    return json.dumps(obj, default=my).replace('"<:<:',"").replace(':>:>"',"")
```

(the "<:<:" & ":>:>" are just added before serialization, to be replaced, post json serialization, to obtain the desired result)

It's a little be hacky, using string substitution to obtain the result ... it works ;-)

I ask myself, and you, if it can be done in a better/python way ...
Do you have any idea ?

**EDIT**
I would like to rewrite my stringify, in a better way, with assertions :

```py
assert stringify( dict(a="hello",b=b"byte") ) == '{"a": "hello", "b": byte}'
assert stringify( ["hello", b"world"] ) == '["hello", world]'
assert stringify( "hello" ) == '"hello"'
assert stringify( b"world" ) == "world"
```

Comment: Your desired result is not valid json ...

Comment: Do you mean `{'a': 'hello', 'b': 'list'}`?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clarify what you want. `"b": list` is not valid JSON and it is totally unclear how code inserting `<:<:` `:>:>` to remove *required* quotes relates to your goal of creating JSON.

Comment: @JamiuS. no ... i've got a key which contain a byte ...
i would like to serialize in a string ...

Comment: Your desired output is this? `{"a": "hello", "b": "list"}` ?

Comment: @no_hex .. no, I really want `'{"a": "hello", "b": list}'` (which is not really json !)

Comment: You want the value to be the actual type `list`? so that you can call `dictionary['b']((1,2,3))`?

Comment: @no_hex ... not 'list' is a arbitary word ... in fact, i would like, that every byte'string are serialized in a string, but without quotes (ex: b'mymethod' -> mymethod, and not "mymethod")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve your desired output, i.e. `'{"a": "hello", "b": list}'` you will need to do some ugly, but fair cosmetic changes, such as reconstructing the dictionary by yourself. As the plain old dictionary `{"a": "hello", "b": list}` makes no sense as a python variable (well, this specific example does, only because we're using the built-in `list`, but if it was "mymethod" or anything else - it wouldn't)

```py
def stringify(input_dict: dict):
    for k, v in input_dict.items():
        if isinstance(v, bytes):
            input_dict[k] = v.decode()
        else:
            input_dict[k] = f'"{v}"'
    return '{' + ', '.join([f'{k}: {v}' for k, v in input_dict.items()]) + '}'
```

We can see that here we are reconstructing literally a dictionary using ASCII characters, not that bad, not that intuitive but nontheless works as intended.
Your solution does work, but it wouldn't work if one of the values in the dictionary has this special set of characters `<:<:`.

---

Making this code:

```py
d = {"a": "hello", "b": b"list"}
serialized_dict = stringify(d)
print(serialized_dict)
```

Output:

```
{a: "hello", b: list}
```

Which is of type `str`, *NOT* a valid JSON one.

---

#### Edit - a more generic `stringify` function.

We can do it smarter, making it recursively call the `stringify` function and if we encounter an atomic object (i.e. `int`, `str` etc..) we return it **with** quotation marks, else (i.e. `bytes`) we return it **without** quotation marks.

```py
def generic_stringify(input_generic_object):
    if isinstance(input_generic_object, dict):
        <paste the stringify function Ive posted above>

    elif isinstance(input_generic_object, list):
        return '[' + ', '.join([generic_stringify(v) for v in input_generic_object]) + ']'

    elif isinstance(input_generic_object, bytes):
        return input_generic_object.decode()
    
    else:
        return f'"{input_generic_object}"'
```

Here we return the bytes decoded if the type is `bytes` and return it with quotation marks if it is of type `str`:

```py
print(generic_stringify(dict(a="hello", b=b"byte")))
print(generic_stringify(["hello", b"world", {"c": b"list"}]))
print(generic_stringify("hello"))
print(generic_stringify(b"world"))
```

Outputs:

```
{"a": "hello", "b": byte}
["hello", world, {"c": list}]
"hello"
world
```

Comment: My solution works (except if value contains "<:<:"), and works for all types (my stringify can eat every kind of objects (dict, list ...) ...
but you're righ, I need to override the default dict serialization !

Comment: @manatlan Sorry, I meant to write "your solution does work", but will not work if the values contain `<:<:` which is the "protocol" you built for yourself, maybe the values will never contain this set of characters :-)

Comment: @manatlan My function will not know how to deal with objects other than dictionaries, it was not specified in your original question though. Your desired method is much more robust and not specific to a dictionary or a list, I think it should be in another question..

Comment: you'll right .... but Don't want to poluate SO with my dumbs questions ... So I edited it, to make it clearer

Comment: @manatlan What about complex objects? such as `[a, b"b", {"c": b"list"}]` (list containing a dictionary)

Comment: you are a god ... I was trying to write something like that, but you were speedier. ...

Comment: I thought that there was a simpler python/json way to resolve that ... but no, you'll need to test each types, and render each types ... so I consider keeping my solution (shortest and simplest) ;-(
thanks a lot

Comment: @manatlan Thanks for the compliments :) you're very welcome any time!